# MessageBox - Both buttons doing the same thing?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want it so that a menustrip item called 'Exit' brings up a MessageBox asking the user if they really wish to exit, but no matter if they click Yes or No, it still exits the program.

```
private void Exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Shows a prompt asking the user if they really want to exit
        DialogResult dQuit;

        dQuit = MessageBox.Show("Do you really wish to exit?",
                                 "Exit?",
                                 MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                                 MessageBoxIcon.Question);

        // If 'Yes' button is clicked, close the program
        if (dQuit == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            Application.Exit();

        }
        else
        {
            // Else, close the dialog box and return to the menu screen
            this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why?... you can just have a messagebox saying exiting with an ok button if thats really what you need

Comment: I don't know why you would want such a behavior. But in that case, why display a MessageBox at all? Simply exit without asking the user.

Comment: What is the code that calls `ShowDialog()` for this dialog like?

Comment: This is absolutely the silliest of silly things to do—voting to close as "too localized" for want of a "too silly" reason.

Answer (score 4):

You're closing the form itself by using the code

```
this.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No;
```

in your `else` block.

You don't have to do anything to close the MessageBox; it gets closed automatically whenever the user clicks one of the buttons. The `MessageBox.Show` method does not return until the MessageBox is already closed.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this without `else` :

```
 if (MessageBox.Show("Do you really wish to exit?", "Exit?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
   {
     Application.Exit();
   }
```

Comment: I wouldnt even have the `if`, just messagebox show then app exit (i mean i would if i ever wanted to do this)

Comment: then how will you capture `DialogResult` ?

Comment: it doesn't matter about capturing it, because he wants to do the same regardless

Comment: fair enough didn't want to post an almost identical answer (logically) and undermine you

Answer (score 1):

```
 MessageBox.Show("Do you really wish to exit?", "Exit?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
 Application.Exit();
```

I would strongly discourage doing this at all though as it is poor for user usability

Comment: did you tested your answer, it works in the both cases(buttons)

Comment: this answer responds to the users question 
" but no matter if they click Yes or No, it still exits the program."

Comment: then whats the need of `MessageBox`?

Comment: well i suppose it would be nice to tell the user its closing :) not my program lol